# Баг с отправкой комментария к чужому вопросу, на который ты объявляешь конкурс

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, репутация, конкурс

Обнаружил прискорбнейший баг. Если назначить на чужой вопрос конкурс, и после объявления конкурса твоя репутация станет ниже `50`, то нельзя будет оставить к нему комментарий, что противоречит логике и здравому смыслу.

Comment: А зачем править вопрос по своему вкусу, если смысловая нагрузка от этого не поменялась и ничего не улучшилось?

Comment: Ваш вопрос стал лучше :) Как минимум, улучшилась пунктуация. Читать стало легче.

Comment: А по поводу правки этого вопроса - это тоже личное мнение каждого. Я бы хотел, чтобы он остался в первозданном виде. Где тут улучшилась пунктуация?

Comment: "Где тут улучшилась пунктуация?", — поставлены 3 запятые в сложных предложениях (заголовок и 2-ое предложение вопроса), поставлена точка (последнее предложение). На мой взгляд, приемлемая правка, улучшающая вопрос.

Comment: Там не нужны запятые. Но можно забить на этот факт.

Comment: @nomnoms12 добавленная в тексте запятая всё-таки не нужна: тут однородные придаточные.

Comment: @andreymal Одна из добавленных действительно не нужна, Вы правы. Но мы что-то слишком далеко от темы вопроса ушли :) Предлагаю закрыть эту тему.

Comment: @nomnoms12 ты вроде оперировал запятыми в этом вопросе, а сейчас это выглядит как слив

Comment: @РашенБеар Признаю, что одна запятая лишняя и я частично был не прав. Вы можете считать, что это слив, но я просто не хочу переводить обсуждение правки в детальное разбирательство. Это мелочи, которые не касаются сути вопроса. Думаю, что Андрей исходил из добрых побуждений, внося правку, и допустил ошибку случайно. Последний голос здесь будет всегда за Вами.

Comment: @РашенБеар как минимум, я поправил ошибку в заголовке и добавил нужные метки. Если с какими-то правками вы не согласны, то всегда можете их откатить.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik не всегда. Еще один баг. И нас тут не очень много (я один)

Answer (score 3):

Эта же проблема была поднята на [основной Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246684/383809). Я так понимаю, сценарий развития событий тот же:

1. У пользователя репутация `X>75` (75 репутации необходимо для осуществление пункта 2 сценария).
2. Он находит вопрос другого пользователя интересным для себя и назначает конкурс с наградой `Y` репутации.
3. По итогу, остается `(X-Y)<50` репутации.
4. Пользователь хочет оставить комментарий под этим вопросом, но имеет меньше необходимых для этого 50 репутации.

Мысли:

1. Оставить комментарий до назначения конкурса. Обычно, уже поздно.
2. Комментарии обычно необходимы для уточнения самого вопроса. Поэтому, в некоторых случаях их использование не является желательным. Часть информации можно добавить в конкурсное сообщение (в частности то, что вы ожидаете от ответа, который собираетесь наградить), которое однако не редактируется.
3. Очевидно, что существуют случаи, когда комментарий нужен, но оставить его не представляется возможным.
4. Пока можно только советовать не начинать конкурсов до достижения репутации в 100 (и следить за размером награды `Y`, чтобы `X-Y>50`).

Я оставил конкурс на вышеуказанный вопрос на основной мете, возможно это привлечет внимание. <s>[Проголосуйте, если считаете оправданным и важным](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246684/383809).</s> -> [статус-отклонено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be): [Официальный ответ от сотрудника Stack Overflow на общей мете.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361159/383809)

Связанные проблемы и обсуждения на основной мете:

- [предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5): [Уведомлять пользователя, когда установка награды повлечет отзыв привилегий](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11930/383809)
- [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5): [Оправдан ли отзыв привилегий после установки награды?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4780/383809)
- [предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5): [Комментировать на посты, где у вас открыт конкурс](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192403/383809) (отчасти дубликат, но я нашел его позже)

Comment: *Я оставил конкурс на вышеуказанный вопрос на основной мете* и теперь не могу написать там комментарий :)